# Using an aggregated outcome variable as contextual in multilevel analysis

Tags: multilevel-analysis, aggregation

A main hypothesis in our study is that people’s decisions (our dichotomous outcome variable) are influenced by how people in their social context have decided in the same matter.

In a multilevel analysis perspective, is it feasible to use as a level 2, or contextual variable, the aggregated (mean) of the outcome variable?

Comment: Late to the game, I know, but this question was picked up on Gelman's blog: http://andrewgelman.com/2013/09/30/using-the-aggregate-of-the-outcome-variable-as-a-group-level-predictor-in-a-hierarchical-model/